# How to identify a linear Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

This exercise is from "Lie groups beyond an introduction, Knapp": Identify the linear Lie algebra of

$$
G=\left\{ 
 \begin{bmatrix}
    a  & z  \\
    0  & a^{-1} 
\end{bmatrix} \quad \Bigg| \quad a\gt 0, \quad z\in\mathbb{C}\right\}
$$

I was thinking of using an explicit formula for the exponential of a $2\times 2$ matrix, such as the one at the end of this page:

mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixExponential.html

And then using the fact that the linear Lie algebra is

$$
\mathcal{g}= \{ X\in M_n(\mathbb{C})\quad|\quad \exp(tX)\in G\quad\mbox{for all }t\in\mathbb{R} \}.
$$
But I think this won't give a "nice" answer, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Just differentiate a matrix in $G$ with respect to $a$ or $z$, and evaluate at $a=1,z=0$. By some definitions, a Lie group's Lie algebra is "the derivative at the identity".

Comment: Differentiate a *matrix* in the group

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Matrix_Lie_algebras

Answer (score 1):

Two parameters, so two generators, so one commutation relation. Has to be the [affine group in one dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Two_dimensions), where the diagonal generator is doubled and shifted by subtraction of the identity matrix.

$$
G= 
 \begin{bmatrix}
    a  & z  \\
    0  & a^{-1} 
\end{bmatrix}  
$$
is the identity for $a=1, z=0$. At the identity, then you have $$
\partial G/\partial a  \to  \begin{bmatrix}
    1  & 0  \\
    0  &  -1 
\end{bmatrix} \equiv x ~, $$
and 
$$
\partial G/\partial z  \to  \begin{bmatrix}
    0  & 1  \\
    0  &  0 
\end{bmatrix} \equiv y ~, $$
so, then,
$$
[x,y]=2y .
$$

The conventional WP normalization redefines your *x* to $\omega\equiv (x+1\!\!1)/2$
to yield $[\omega,y]=y$. Exponentiating an arbitrary linear combination of these two Lie algebra elements yields the generic form *G* you started with, since the relevant [CBH expansion sums elegantly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Special_cases) to a simple closed form: your starting point.

Consider the wisecrack
$$
G= 
 \begin{bmatrix}
    a  & z  \\
    0  & a^{-1} 
\end{bmatrix} = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
    a  & 0  \\
    0  & a^{-1} 
\end{bmatrix}  
 \begin{bmatrix}
    1  & z/a  \\
    0  & 1 
\end{bmatrix} = e^{(\ln a) ~x}  e^{(z/a) y}
$$
and its CBH contraction.